# How to get an Ubuntu root account to forward ssh keys as the forwarding machine

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, ssh-agent

UPDATE: the whole thing described below works fine for *non-root* accounts on the remote machine.

That is, this works:

```
anderson@client -> nonroot@remote -> anderson's-ssh-key@github.com
```

This does *not* work, however:

```
anderson@client -> root@remote -> anderson's-ssh-key@github.com
```

So the question is actually, how do I make ssh agent forwarding work when the machine in the middle is root?

---

Local machine (OSX) has forwarding turned on in the ~/.ssh/config file:

```
Host remotehost
    ForwardAgent yes
```

Local machine does not override this setting in /etc/ssh/ssh_config.

```
Host *
#   ForwardAgent no
```

Local machine is running ssh-agent:

```
anderson$ ssh-agent
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-L0iFZ891Gv/agent.75083; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=75084; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 75084;
```

ssh-add has been performed on the key:

```
anderson$ ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Passphrase updated in keychain: /Users/anderson/.ssh/id_rsa
Identity added: /Users/anderson/.ssh/id_rsa (/Users/anderson/.ssh/id_rsa)
```

$SSH_AUTH_SOCK is there:

```
anderson$ echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
/tmp/launch-pg2gVc/Listeners
```

ssh key has been uploaded to GitHub and is working:

```
anderson$ ssh -T git@github.com
Hi [elided]! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Remote machine (Ubuntu 12.04LTS) has the public ssh key from the local machine and it works:

```
anderson$ ssh root@remotehost
[root@host1~]#
```

Remote machine has AllowAgentForwarding configured:

```
[root@host1~]# head /etc/ssh/sshd_config
# Package generated configuration file
# See the sshd_config(5) manpage for details

AllowAgentForwarding yes
```

And here's where it goes pear-shaped: SSH_AUTH_SOCK is nowhere to be found on the remote:

```
[root@host1~]# echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK

**crickets**
```

And of course key forwarding is nowhere to be found as well:

```
[root@host1~]# ssh -T git@github.com
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Even forcing it like this doesn't work:

```
anderson$ ssh -A root@remotehost
```

Debug output:

```
anderson$ ssh -vvv -A root@remotehost
OpenSSH_5.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/anderson/.ssh/config
debug1: Applying options for remotehost
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: mux_client_hello_exchange: master version 4
debug3: mux_client_request_forwards: requesting forwardings: 0 local, 0 remote
debug3: mux_client_request_session: entering
debug3: mux_client_request_alive: entering
debug3: mux_client_request_alive: done pid = 45287
debug3: mux_client_request_session: session request sent
debug1: mux_client_request_session: master session id: 3
```

So am I missing something? It seems to me I've covered all of the bases for debugging. Any ideas on what else I can check?

Comment: Why are you sshing as root anyway?

Comment: I knew someone would ask that. :-) Long story short, there's no good reason other than to change it right now would take more time than I have. Certainly before this goes production I want to have everything sorted into user accounts, but that's going to take a lot of work for reasons I won't get into right now.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar case, and the reason was that wrapper I was using was setting `ControlPath` option, and SSH also was stuck at `debug1: mux_client_request_session: master session id: 3`. Removing a directory specified in `ControlPath` has resolved the issue.